# Using Pandas to extract data from multiple columns to create a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, integer, multiple-columns

I want to create 3 new columns which takes the spend for each channel type for a specific date. Channel column can either be Display, search or social

[image]

this is the output I would like to achieve but now sure how to go about it (do not want to do this manually)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3dww.png)

Comment: Hey, you might want to take a look at how to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question.

Comment: thanks for flagging ive corrected the question

Comment: If you can, share a sample data and explain how do you want to create new columns. Your question is not well explained. We cannot help you like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is honestly confusing. But based on your desired output I am going to assume that you want to pivot your dataframe so that the channels are columns and the dates are the index.
If for each channel, each date appears only once, this should work:

```
df.set_index(['Channel', 'Date'])['Spend'].unstack('Channel')
```

If that was not the case, and for example you wanted to add all the spends in the same channel and date, I would do something like this:

```
df.groupby(['Channel', 'Date'])['Spend'].sum().unstack('Channel')
```